# Would it be fine to apply for an E-Visa for Thailand with a bus ticket to leave the country?

Tags: air-travel, italy, thailand, business-travel, e-visas

I have to apply for an E-Visa for Thailand. The embassy requires a ticket to leave the country. Would it be fine if I bought a bus ticket instead of a flight ticket?